# Photoshop action to export icon resources for OS X app?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, workflow, actions

Is there a photoshop action for exporting a 1024x1024 canvas as all the required icon resources for a OS X app?

Seems like something the design community would have made, but I can't find anything so thought I'd ask.

```
Filename                Size of canvas (in pixels) 

icon_512x512@2x         1024x1024 
icon_512x512            512x512 
icon_256x256@2x         512x512 
icon_256x256            256x256 
icon_128x128@2x         256x256 
icon_128x128            128x128 
icon_32x32@2x           64x64 
icon_32x32              32x32 
icon_16x16@2x           32x32 
icon_16x16              16x16
```

Comment: I'm sure others will answer the Script/Action question, but I want to address a design issue.  Unless your design is very simple and has sharp contrast, when you start making icons that are less than 64^2 you'll want to tweak them to make them look better... and for the 32^2 and 16^2 icons, you may want a simpler version of the icon graphics.  This is standard practice.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools and actions for that. One of them is http://appicontemplate.com/ where you paste your app icon once into a Smart Object and export all slices. But recoding your own action should be just as easy.

Comment: I've heard of appicontemplate.com but it's for iOS. I'm looking for something for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You might find something like this helpful:

http://www.appsbynight.com/2012/09/17/create-every-ios-icon-for-your-app-with-a-photoshop-script/

Haven't tried it myself, but it seems to export all standard ios icon sizes